# shading certain area in R

Tags: r, plot

I met a problem when shading some areas by using function polygon in R. if these areas have common parts, the last shaded one will cover the previous one. But now, I do want do see this phenomenon and want to keep the original boundaries. what should I do? 
see the following image as an example:

the codes for drawing this image are:

```
plot(variance_five[51:60,2],type="n",ylim=c(0,0.1))
for(i in 1:6)
{
   polygon(c(1:10,10:1),c(variance_five[(10*i-9):(10*i),1],variance_five[(10*i):    (10*i-9),3]),lty=2,col=i)
   lines(variance_five[(10*i-9):(10*i),2])
}
```

we can see that the last shaded area(purple) covers some blue and light blue parts, what shall I do keep all the boundaries of all areas and the colour in the common areas are the sum effect of these colours? Thank you!

Comment: We do not have access to `variance_five` so cannot easily help as it stands. Perhaps pasting the output of `dput( head( variance_five ) )` as a code block into your question will help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use transparency. The function `alpha` in the `scales` package will add transparency to any color. I'd recommend setting up a vector of colors before the loop and making them transparent, e.g.

```
my_colors <- rainbow(6)
require(scales)
my_colors <- alpha(my_colors, alpha = 0.5)
```

And then inside the loop replacing `col = i` with `col = my_colors[i]`.
You can, of course, adjust the alpha level (0 is completely transparent, 1 completely opaque) as necessary. The scales package also provides a function `show_col` which I find useful in picking colors. Try

```
show_col(rainbow(6))
show_col(heat.colors(6))
show_col(cm.colors(6))
```

I should note that `rainbow` et al. take `alpha` as an argument, so you don't *need* the alpha function, but it's more general to use the `alpha` function which will work on other R colors if you've got favorites. (I like `dodgerblue2` and `firebrick4`, personally.)

Comment: Great! I succeeded in realizing my goal according to you advice, thanks!